# Receive (bind) the data coming from two select commands n a single proc in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
 create proc [dbo].[SpCateProducts](@cate_id int)
    as
begin
    select sb.subcate_name, sum(p.qty)
    from subcategory sb 
      join product p on p.subcate_id = sb.subcate_id
    where sb.cate_id = @cate_id
    group by sb.subcate_name

        select top 1 pname from product join subcategory
    on product.subcate_id=
    (
        select top 1 subcate_id
        from subcategory
        where cate_id=3
        order by NEWID()
    )
end
```

but it is returning two tables, then how can I bind it to the listview?

Or is there any way that it will returns a single table, which will contain all these required rows of data?

I mean that that 1st one select command already giving a table of 4 rows and 4 columns, then is there any way that it will contain one more column (`pname`) which is currently returning by 2nd select command

Answer (score 0):

Try using with statement for both tables. Then use simple join over tables.

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to accomplished but something like
`create proc [dbo].[SpCateProducts](@cate_id int)
    as
begin
    with tbl1 as
    (select sb.subcate_name, sum(p.qty)
    from subcategory sb 
      join product p on p.subcate_id = sb.subcate_id
    where sb.cate_id = @cate_id
    group by sb.subcate_name)

    with tbl2 as(
        select top 1 pname from product join subcategory
    on product.subcate_id=
    (
        select top 1 subcate_id
        from subcategory
        where cate_id=3
        order by NEWID()
    ))

    select * from tbl1 join tbl2
end`